# SQL JOIN two different columns on the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a MySQL Database Table that indicates the relations between some entries in my database. the table has 4 columns:
(the table name is: RelationsTable)

```
 id |  type | relationId | relationType
 1 |  customer | 5 | recipt
 2 |  recipt | 4 | customer
```

I'm trying to add this table's data to another table that contains a customer ID. But since the customer's ID might appear both as RelationsTable.id or RelationsTable.relationId , I can't use a normal JOIN.
What should I do?

thanks!

Comment: Please give an example of what data you want to insert into the other table?

Comment: Please show the code you've tried and what went wrong.

Comment: If customer's ID appear both for as id and relationid which one takes precedence? Or do you want to appear both?

Comment: JOIN RelationsTable ON NewTable.customerId=RelationsTable.id JOIN RelationsTable ON NewTable.customerId=RelationsTable.relationId

Answer (score 0):

you just need to link it, try this

```
select * from table1, table2 where table1.customer_id = table2.customer_id;
```

if still error change to

```
select * from table1, table2 where table1.customer_id == table2.customer_id;
```

Comment: Double equals sign is not valid in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/comparison-operators.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the customer table twice, to both columns with different aliases for the customer table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here with not much info from your post.

You probably need this:

```
SELECT RT.id, Cust.Lastname, Cust.Firstname
FROM RelationsTable RT INNER JOIN Customers Cust
ON RT.id = Cust.id
WHERE RT.type = 'customer'
UNION ALL
SELECT RT.relationid, Cust.Lastname, Cust.Firstname
FROM RelationsTable RT INNER JOIN Customers Cust
ON RT.relationid = Cust.id
WHERE RT.relationtype = 'customer'
```